# What really happens when I drop a column from a table?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I have an MS SQL Server database. I was just doing some experiments with how long certain operations would take so we can minimize down time on our web site when we update the db. I need to change the definition of a column, but the table is big, so this takes two hours. So plan B: I created a new column, copied data from the old column to the new column, deleted the old column, and renamed the new column to the name of the old column. (I was thinking we could copy the data with the web site still running, then just bring it down long enough to do the drop and rename. Maybe that's a dumb idea because how would I make sure that records were not updated while the copy was happening, but that's all beside the point of this question.)

Now here's the part that puzzles me:

`alter table add column:` 0 seconds. Okay, I figure it just adds an entry to meta data, and the engine is smart enough to deal with columns where the value hasn't been filled in yet.

`update set newcolumn=oldcolumn` 2 hours. That's what I expected.

`Delete oldcolumn`: 0 seconds.

Now that puzzles me. If it takes 2 hours to copy the data, okay deleting doesn't involve doing type format conversions, I could see it would be faster, but I can't imagine it could process millions of records in less than 1 second. So it must just be updating metadata. But then, the data must still be out there on millions of records taking up disk space and having to be read when we read records, etc. Do deleted columns then hang around forever? Do they get cleaned up one record at a time as records are updated? Do they get cleaned up by some background job? Maybe I should do some more experiments: does it normally take longer to do a delete, really going and updating all the records, but for some reason this was a special case?

In my experiment the column was `nvarchar(max)` with typically 1000 characters or so per record. As the other columns total about 150 bytes, this column is the bulk of the table, so it's not a moot question.

Comment: As I understand it, `large value types` *default* to being stored `out-of-row`.  I suspect you would get different timings and behaviour if, for example, migrating from INT to BIGINT.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189087%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @MatBailie According to the TSQL documentation -- which I looked up when this whole issue came up -- TEXT fields are stored out-of-row, but VARCHAR(MAX) fields are stored in-row when the size is below some threshold (I think it was 8k) and out-of-row when above that threshold. In my case, all of the rows in the table had this field below the threshold. That's why, by the way, I was changing the data type: It dramatically improved performance.

Answer (score 0):

the update takes it´s time because it has to duplicate data.

dropping the column just adjust some metadata, but leaves the actual data untouched. the space where it resides it just marked as free and can be overwritten anytime storage space is needed.
until then it can even be possible to revert the drop column.